# Looking for CRM, ERP, ITSM solution for IT development business

Tags: wiki, crm, knowledge-base, support-tracker

Currently information about customers, support tickets, contracts, market leads etc. is spread across multiple solutions.
Development team uses Confluence and Jira, but for the other teams we the need to find some new and innovative solution that can help us give the customers a great customer service.

After researching the web I have found some possible solutions that may help us.

- mHelpDesk
- Zoho
- Saleforce

But is there any other solutions out there that cover the following:

- Help desk, Service desk, ticket system.
- Sosial media interaction
- Field Service. (Prefer through mobile phone app)
- Knowledge base, Wiki.
- Sales, Marking and Project tools (CRM).
- Customers Contract, License and Assets management.
- Call center, for IP phone/SoftPhone.

Also useful to us:

- Integration between Help/Service desk and Jira.
- Web/cloud based or on premises.
- API or SDK, for developing add ons.

We have no budget limit.

Comment: Most of your requirements are met by *Trac* (see [my other answers describing Trac](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=trac+user%3A185)), together with the appropriate plugins/addons. Call center/IPphone probably not. As *Trac* is open source (written in Python), you can easily adjust/extend it to your needs. Worth a look I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Why not [JIRA Service Desk](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/service-desk)? Its an offshoot of JIRA so will integrate seamlessly with your Developers current JIRA setup, tickets can be pushed to Developers JIRA as needed. As well as a service desk ticketing system, can use Confluence to create a self-service Knowledge Base wiki that both customers and service desk agents customers can search. Customers can access a public portal to search the KB, raise support tickets and track ticket progress.

It has email integration that allows emails to your support email address to automatically create support tickets. The email handler can also detect keywords in emailed requests and auto-reply back with matching KB articles that may answer the query.

The portal can also automate the onboarding of new customers, setting up contract and license agreements without direct handholding.

And there's an API for developing add ons and a marketplace for buying/selling add ons.